# VBA - Trying to Input text and click Search button, All within a Table, within a Form, No ID Element, only Class Element

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Trying to input a Value into an Input Box and press the Search button to get the results from a table.

I can't seem to figure out how to input the Value into the Box. The input box and button seems to be inside a form inside a table. No ID element.

```
**> Input Box has these properties**
<td Class = "searchRow">
<input type = "text" name = "name" value onblur = "Numberfield();" style = "width: 200px;" class = "required">
This is all inside Form ID "SearchForm" > div ID "Search" > Tr > Td CLass "searchRow"
```

> After I grab the correct internet explorer tab, I need to getElementByClassName and inp9ut value

```
 IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr").getElementsByTagName("input").Value = "Search"
 IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchRow").getElementsByTagName("input").Value = "Search"
```

> I can't seem to get any combination to work.

Another element is the Button.

```
Button has these properties
<td colspan = "6" style = "align:right;" class = "searchonly">
<input type = "button" class = "actionbutton" value = "search" onclick = "submitform()">
```

How do i Click this button that is in the Table Row.

```
 IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchonly").getElementsByTagName("actionbutton").Click
```

Does this make sense?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add ID attribute and then use getElementsByID.

And If that is not possible then you can use XPATH and get the element by using following function.

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
console.log( getElementByXpath("VALUE OF XPATH") );
```

And you can easily get the XPATH by using the extension in any browser. Like XPath Finder available in google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I write the Answer as comments and code:

```
'What you want first
'**> Input Box has these properties**
'<td Class = "searchRow">
' <input type = "text" name = "name" value onblur = "Numberfield();" style = "width: 200px;" class = "required">
'This is all inside Form ID "SearchForm" > div ID "Search" > Tr > Td CLass "searchRow"

'What you try
'IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr").getElementsByTagName("input").Value = "Search"
'IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchRow").getElementsByTagName("input").Value = "Search"

'What should work
'Attention: the get methods work case sensitive. It's a difference between "Search" and "search"
'I write that because I wonder if the first letter of the ID "Search" is upper case in the original document
'
'You can seperate the div tag include all inner tags as own DOM object
Dim nodeDivSearch As Object
Set nodeDivSearch = IE.Document.getElementByID("Search")
'
'Now you can work on the new DOM object only
'Note that the getElements methods always create a NodeCollection
'All elements of the collection have an index. The first element always has
'index 0, so you can access the first input tag in the new DOM object as follows
'(getElementByID does not create a NodeCollection, because an ID should always
'be unique. So there is only one element for this criterion anyway)
nodeDivSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Search"
'
'I think your code will work with setting indexes
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchRow")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Search"


'What you want second
'Button has these properties
'<td colspan = "6" style = "align:right;" class = "searchonly">
'  <input type = "button" class = "actionbutton" value = "search" onclick = "submitform()">

'What you try:
'IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchonly").getElementsByTagName("actionbutton").Click

'I think you know what to do here
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchonly")(0).getElementsByTagName("actionbutton")(0).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. So you need to choose which element you need using index in the returned array. So does it with `getElementsByTagName`.

So if the html code is like below:

```
<form id="SearchForm">
    <div id="Search">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td Class="searchRow">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value onblur="Numberfield();" style="width: 200px;" class="required" id="a1">
                </td>
                <td colspan="6" style="align:right;" class="searchonly">
                    <input type="button" class="actionbutton" value="search" onclick="submitform()">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then the vba code to set value and click button should be like below:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchRow")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "Search"

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("searchonly")(0).getElementsByClassName("actionbutton")(0).Click
```

The code above is just for example, you should change the index according to the actual situation of the website you visit.